# How to move exisiting elements between packages with an EA Addin in c#?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am working on an EA Addin in c# (thanks Geert) and would like to move exisiting elements from a package to another using the code.

It is clear how to add or delete elements to/from EA.Collection p.Elements, but this does not work sincethis procedure changes the GUID of the element.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You're welcome ;) I see Thomas already answered your question. You should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You simply need to change the `packageId` property to be that of the new package and you're done. Don't forget the `update()` after you changed it.

Additionally you can change the position in the browser with `TreePos` in which case you should explicitly number all elements that are listed for the according package. Ordering ad hoc will likely produce strange results since the sort order in EA is - I have no words for that ;-)

Comment: This perfectly suits my problem, I already tried it out. Many thx for the quick answer :)

Comment: Thanks for asking here. On Sparx forum it's just for the honor (well, I can plug my books) but here I collect points ;-)