# Moving Elements from one packe to another package

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have  Package-A in which we have 10 class elements.We have another Package-B .Now we want to move the elements present in Package-A to Package-B through Addin.How can this be achieved in EA through Addin

Even for moving sub-packages from package-A to package-B is the same thing works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move exisiting elements between packages with an EA Addin in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819597/how-to-move-exisiting-elements-between-packages-with-an-ea-addin-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the PackageID property for all the class elements with PackageB ID .

sample code somethinglike

```
foreach(EA.Element classElement in PackageA.elements)
{
    classElement.PackageID = packageb.PackageID : 
    classElement.Update();
}
```

Comment: Can we move the set of elements at a time.

Comment: @ManuV No you can't move through EA API

Comment: Can we move packages also the same way

Comment: @ManuV yes you can

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it at once without any script, through SQL.
Do this in the SQL Scratchpad in EA.

[image]

Copy the GUID of the target package in the clipboard, say {61068DDF-335B-4b29-89F8-C54A7000EF6F})

[image: Copy GUID]

Its package id is the following:

```
select Package_ID from t_package where ea_guid='{61068DDF-335B-4b29-89F8-C54A7000EF6F}'
```

Copy the GUID of the source package in the clipboard, say {F3B52DA0-D9E9-4606-BCA0-5D211B73FBE6}.

Its package id is the following:

```
select Package_ID from t_package where ea_guid='{F3B52DA0-D9E9-4606-BCA0-5D211B73FBE6}'
```

So, elements in source package are:

```
select * from t_object where Package_ID=(select Package_ID from t_package where ea_guid='{F3B52DA0-D9E9-4606-BCA0-5D211B73FBE6}')
```

So, let's make that go to the target.

```
update t_object 
set Package_ID=(select Package_ID from t_package where ea_guid='{61068DDF-335B-4b29-89F8-C54A7000EF6F}'
where Package_ID=(
select Package_ID from t_package where ea_guid='{F3B52DA0-D9E9-4606-BCA0-5D211B73FBE6}'
)
```

Should do the trick.

Backup your model first.

For an Add-In, it is just a matter of getting the two GUIDs, and  Repository.Execute(theSQLString).

Repository.Execute is not in the doc, but works.